# Generic check to avoid dangerous rm's in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile, attached to a project I am semi-maintaining, but did not originally write. This Makefile does, at the moment, have a nasty habit of running "rm *" on a `make clean` run when certain variables are not defined.

It includes, for example:
 `rm $(SOMEDIR)/$(SOMEPREFIX)*` and `rm $(SOMEPREFIX)*`

There are several sets of variables like this. Is there a simple way to make sure that we're not ever going to accidentally call something like `rm *` or `rm /*`?

I could, of course, check all of the combinations of `$SOMEDIR` and `$SOMEPREFIX` individually, but it'd be nice to do something safer that doesn't require each individual variable/command to be checked.

Any ideas that don't involve me rewriting the whole thing?

Comment: If the variables are supposed to be normally defined on command line, you can add default values in the makefile. If you do define them on command line, they will be overridden: [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html)

Comment: If the vars are supposed to be normally defined in another makefile that is included, you can use `FOO ?= bar` syntax. This will only assign it if the variable doesn't yet exist. [Docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors)

Answer (score 3):

Very frequently the list of generated files that you want to delete on `make clean` can be computed from a list of (precious) source files:

```
ROOTDIR = .
OBJDIR  = objdir
$(SRCS) = $(wildcard *.c)
$(OBJS) = $(patsubst %.c,$(ROOTDIR)/$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))
```

To avoid catastrophic `make clean` consequences, prefer deleting computed file lists over unpredictable glob patterns:

```
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)
```

is much better than:

```
clean:
    rm -f $(ROOTDIR)/$(OBJDIR)/*
```

Answer (score 2):

@Renaud Pacalet's is a better solution.  If for some reason it doesn't fit your situation, you can give the variables a value if otherwise unset using `?=`.

E.g.

```
ROOTDIR ?= /tmp/nonexistant
OBJDIR  ?= NOPE
```

Or maybe just put an error check at the top to prompt the user to set the variables appropriately. (An empty string in `if` triggers the `else` case)

```
$(if $(ROOTDIR),,$(error Please set ROOTDIR))
$(if $(OBJDIR),,$(error Please set OBJDIR))
```

Answer (score 0):

Safest solution I've found so far is to avoid `rm -r` at all costs.

Instead, use `rm` specifying the files individually, possibly using globs or via `find -exec` command. Or at least use `rm -r` but with literal strings as part of the parameters.

Finally, remove parent directories with `rmdir`.

So in other words there doesn't seem to be a bullet-proof way considering accidental/malicious changes to the Makefile variables.

As an example, instead of doing this:

```
clean:
    rm -f -r $(VENDOR)
```

Better do this:

```
clean:
    rm -f -r $(VENDOR)/*.com
    rm -f -r $(VENDOR)/*.org
    rm -f    $(VENDOR)/modules.txt
    rmdir    $(VENDOR) 2> /dev/null || true
```